# Application of Abel's theorem

Tags: real-analysis

The theorem states that suppose $f(x) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} a_nx^n$ has radius of convergence $0 < R < +\infty$. If the series converges at $x = \pm R$, then $f$ is continuous at $x = \pm R$.

Given the series $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n + 1}}{n}$. Since it is convergent, then by Abel's theorem, $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n + 1}}{n} = ln(2)$

I am confused as to how that conclusion is true. I know that the series' radius of convergence is $ R = 1$, and the series converges at $x = \pm 1$. Then the series is continuous at $x = \pm 1$. But how did $ln(2)$ come about?

Comment: Can you find the Taylor series of $\ln (1+x)$?

Comment: No, could you elaborate?

Comment: For Abel's theorem, you need a power series $\sum c_n x^n$. Now if $f(x) = \sum c_n x^n$ for $\lvert x\rvert < 1$, and $\sum c_n$ converges, then $f(1) = \sum c_n$.

Comment: See [the expansion of $\ln(1+x)$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm#Derivative.2C_Taylor_series).